# Can I override the @RequestMapping on a type for a method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring controller/POJO like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo");
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/bar") 
    public String MyAction() { return someSharedFunc(false); }

    @RequestMapping("/debug/ping");
    public String MyDebugPing() { return someSharedFunc(true); }

    private String someSharedFunc(boolean debug) {
      if(debug) return "FooBar"; else return "Debug!";
    }
}
```

In this scenario, the URL for MyDebugPing is `/foo/debug/ping`. However, I want it to be `/debug/ping`, effectively ignoring the RequestMapping on the class.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just remove the `@RequestMapping` annotation from the class and use full paths per individual methods. E.g.

```
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/foo/bar") 
    public String MyAction() { return someSharedFunc(false); }

    @RequestMapping("/debug/ping");
    public String MyDebugPing() { return someSharedFunc(true); }

    private String someSharedFunc(boolean debug) {
      if(debug) return "FooBar"; else return "Debug!";
    }
}
```

If there is a lot of methods then you can simply move out the method to another controller.

Comment: Thanks. That's my Plan B. There are about a dozen methods, so I'll try to avoid that if I can.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can move out the method from the class (e.g. in the same package in order to be able to access to protected or package visible methods). It will require some work though (change private to package visible etc.).